# How to convert timezone in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, time

I have the query that gets the data for the previous month. However, the time stored in the tables are in UTC (+00:00).

How do I adjust the query to convert the TimeZone from UTC to Australia/Sydney (+10:00) in the query?

My query is:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(pr.start_date,'%b %y') as start,
p.name as publisher,
sum(ifnull(pr.revenue,0)) as revenue
FROM trk.publisher_revenue pr
left outer join publisher p on p.pubid = pr.pubid
where pr.start_date between DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01'),
INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
and pr.status = 1
group by DATE_FORMAT(pr.start_date,'%b %y'),pr.pubid
order by pr.start_date, p.pubid;
```

The column where the date are stored is the start_date. It has the datatype `DATETIME` and the format it is stored is in e.g. 2014-09-01 00:00:00

The only solution for my problem is to adjust the query.

Desired result: Display the data, after converting the TimeZone to 'Australia/Syndey' or GMT +10:00.

Comment: `SET time_zone = 'Australia/Sydney'` before running your query.

Comment: I am plugging this query into an application, hence the requirement as to why I want the TZ conversion in the query :)

Comment: So, what's the problem?  Your application can still issue the `SET` command prior to executing the query, can it not?

Comment: No it can not. Its just a simple reporting application, in which I just have to save the query.

Comment: Well, I have never come across an application—no matter how simple—that cannot issue to the RDBMS two consecutive commands.  Perhaps you should open a new question on this site asking how to accomplish that?

Comment: @qas If you're having problems issuing more than one query, what you need is a stored procedure that can encapsulate all of this and be called with one statement. Keep in mind that time-zone conversion is almost always done in application code and not in the database, as the application code gives you way more control over presentation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get your month boundaries right for a reporting query.

Your `start_date` values are stored in `DATETIME`  data items, so you can convert them to UTC+10:00 like this:

```
 pr.start_date + INTERVAL 10 HOUR
```

Simply rewrite your code to do that. For example, you can get the month in which each row falls with this expression:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(pr.start_date + INTERVAL 10 HOUR,'%b %y')
```

But, there's a complication. The value of the expression `NOW()` depends on your MySQL connection's current time zone setting. This makes a difference for your range selection.  If your time zone setting is UTC, you should apply the same ten-hour offset to `NOW()` and related values.  For example, rewriting the query in your question, you'd get this:

```
where pr.start_date + INTERVAL 10 HOUR
   between
     DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 10 HOUR ,'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   and   /* WRONG ! */
     DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 10 HOUR ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

But, you really can't use `BETWEEN` for date ranges because it includes the end-date of the range, and you want to exclude that.  So your date-selection query should be

```
where pr.start_date + INTERVAL 10 HOUR  >=
     DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 10 HOUR ,'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  and pr.start_date + INTERVAL 10 HOUR <
     DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 10 HOUR ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

Notice the use of `>=` for the start of the date range and `<` for the end.

You probably should refactor that expression so it can exploit a range scan.

```
where pr.start_date  >=
   (DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 10 HOUR ,'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
       - INTERVAL 10 HOUR
  and pr.start_date <
   (DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 10 HOUR ,'%Y-%m-01'))
      - INTERVAL 10 HOUR
```

It looks like there's a lot of redundant adding and subtracting of ten hours going on, but it's necessary because of the date-truncation in the middle of things.

Finally, I believe Sydney's daylight savings time zone, presently in effect, is UTC +11:00 not UTC + 10:00.    You might want to double check your offset.